# border-radius if there is an image on the border

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, css

building a simple website with React using Reactstrap and Bootstrap. I want to set a custom border-radius to my Cards but when it comes to set it on the upper part of the Card, it is not rendered because the image inside of it (white as well) is overlapping the container itself.
Is there a css property to "smoothen" the img border as well? How would you solve this problem?

Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import logo from '../images/logo.png';
import tile1 from '../images/tile_imgs/prova(m).png';
import tile2 from '../images/tile_imgs/prova(d).png';
import tile3 from '../images/tile_imgs/prova(x).png';
import { Card, CardImg, CardText, CardBody,
   CardTitle, CardSubtitle, Button, Col, Row, Container } from 'reactstrap';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
     <div> 
        <div className="App">
            <br/>
            <img src={logo} />
          </div>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <Container className="prova" fluid="true">
              <Row>
                <Col className="frame" xs="12" sm="4">
                  <Card className="card">
                  <CardImg className="cards" src={tile1} />
                    <CardBody>
                      <CardTitle> Recruitment Services</CardTitle>
                      <CardText>Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</CardText>
                      <Button>Discover More!</Button>
                    </CardBody>
                  </Card>
                </Col>
                <Col xs="12" sm="4">
                  <Card>
                  <CardImg className="cards" src={tile2} alt="Card image cap" />
                    <CardBody>
                      <CardTitle>Web Design and Web-mastering</CardTitle>
                      <CardText>Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</CardText>
                      <Button>Discover More!</Button>
                    </CardBody>
                  </Card>
                </Col>
                <Col xs="6" sm="4">
                  <Card>
                  <CardImg className="cards" src={tile3} alt="Card image cap" />
                    <CardBody>
                      <CardTitle>Digital Marketing</CardTitle>
                      <CardText>Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</CardText>
                      <Button>Discover More!</Button>
                    </CardBody>
                  </Card>
                </Col>
              </Row>
              </Container>
              <br/>
              <br/>
     </div>

    );
  }

}


export default App;
```

CSS

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
  background-image:
   url('../images/arch1.jpg'), /*put the first one on the Top*/
   url('../images/computer.jpg'),
   url('../images/arch2.jpg');
  animation: animatedBird 30s infinite;
  height: 26rem;
}

@keyframes animatedBird {
  0% {
    background-image: url('../images/arch1.jpg');
  }
  10% {
    background-image: url('../images/arch1.jpg');
  }
  25% {
    background-image: url('../images/computer.jpg');
  }
  35% {
    background-image: url('../images/computer.jpg');
  }
  50% {
    background-image: url('../images/arch2.jpg');
  }
  60% {
    background-image: url('../images/arch2.jpg');
  }
  75% {
    background-image: url('../images/computer.jpg');
  }
  100% {
    background-image: url('../images/arch1.jpg');
  }
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #222;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.App-title {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

#navbar {
  height: 150px;
}

.cards {
  max-height: 200px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.prova {
  max-width: 80%;
}

.card {
  width: 24rem;
  height: 26rem;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 34px !important;
}

.frame {
  border-radius: 34% !important;
}
```

Comment: overflow:hidden ?

Comment: Did you try overflow:hidden with border-radius ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with *overflow: hidden* on the container's CSS

Comment: Thanks. solved. I did try manually rendering the image and adding custome borders but this is way better